# Installing dependencies in an OpsWorks chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, bower, aws-opsworks

I have a simple static site layer on OpsWorks that has dependencies listed in a `bower.json` file. However, when I run `bower install --allow-root` in my deploy recipe, I get `ENOENT No bower.json present`.  How can I find the correct path of the project in the chef script so I can install bower modules?

Comment: Show your recipe. But an execute resource have a `cwd` attribute to tell in which directory it should run. See [the documentation here](https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html)

Comment: I know how the `cwd` command works, but I'm asking how I can programmatically locate the directory I should use for that command

Comment: Again, show your recipe, I can't guess which provider you're using. The deployment path has to be defined somewhere, without more details it's really hard to guess what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpsWorks provides your recipe with a deploy JSON containing the app directory. Check out [the AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-json.html) for more information about this payload.

Assuming your bower.json is in the root directory of your project, you can add this command in your Chef recipe:

```
node[:deploy].each do |app, deploy|
   execute "bower_install" do
        command "bower install --allow-root"
        cwd "#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current"
   end
end
```

This recipe will perform this task for all your apps in your layer. You can perform it for a specific app by checking the `app` variable value.

The `#{deploy[:deploy_to]}` is your app directory and `current` the symbolic link to your latest release. However, I'd rather perform such things in a [deploy hook script](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-extend-hooks.html) rather than in a deploy recipe because OpsWorks makes your app available before running your deploy recipes. But that's another story.

Hope this helps.